# how to call php function through hypertext link

Tags: javascript, php

I want to call a PHP function passing an argument on clicking a hyperlink (text with `<a>` tag) on the same page, i.e. `href='#' onclick='loadpic($id)`.

Where `$id` is the variable to be passed to PHP function.

Comment: Remote Procedure Call (RPC) ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by ajax easily. Create a loadpic function in javascript instead and then pass $id to the php file via ajax and do something when you get the result.

Your javascript file should look like this- 
(make sure you've inserted a link for jquery in your index file)

```
function loadpic(id_param){
     $.post("filename.php",
     {
          id: id_param
     },
     function(data){
         alert("Data received:" + data);
     });
};
```

The data parameter in function(data) would be the value that you've echoed in the php file.

Comment: Note, `jquery` tag does not appear at Question.

Comment: Implementing something in jquery is definitely easier than js. And user2599097  didnt know the answer and expects it to be in js, thats why there's no such tag (i guess)

Comment: _"Implementing something in jquery is definitely easier than js."_ ? How is this determined?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `onclick()` method in your HTML element then you have to write your method is javascript and make an AJAX call to PHP. THis is one simple way to do this using php and javascript. And for this please see javascript and ajax with PHP.

But if you dont want to use javascript then here is a simple way and very simple code.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['myMethod'])){
    myMethod($_GET['id']);
}
function myMethod($id){
    echo $id."<br>";
}
?>

<?php 
$myId = 4;
?>
<a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $myId ?>&myMethod" >MyLink</a>
```

**Note:** Copy this code and paste into a file called `index.php` because notice the hyper link tag and its attribute `href="index.php"`.

Also note that you can not directly call php method using js like `onclick()` from your HTML tag. You should use AJAX or something. But using above demo code you can easily call `myMethod()` which is a PHP method using the hyper link tag.

**In your case:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['call_loadpic'])){
    loadpic($_GET['id']);
}
function loadpic($id){
    echo "My loadpic method has been called! and the id is".$id."<br />";
}
?>
<!-- your other codes -->

<?php 
$id = 4;
?>
<a href="this-same-file-name.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>&call_loadpic" >MyLink</a>
```

This is because your php function is in the same page and you want to call that function using same file and hyperlink in the same file. (**According to your question**)

Answer (score -1):

You still will have to make javascript handle the exception because php has no onclick.

```
onClick=\"loadpic("'.$id.'");"\
//this will only send a php variable javascript will still have to loadpic();
```